# Is it possible for a PAM module to prevent more than one login for a user?

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

Is it possible to have a PAM module that checks to see if a user attempting login via OpenSSH is already logged in and if they are then deny the 2nd login?

I've tried several other way to prevent more than one login session but nothing is working, if someone can confirm this is doable using a custom PAM module I'd be very grateful, thanks.

I noticed the limits.conf works ok when I comment out the sftp config:

```
# SFTP + Port Forwarding Only for Normal Users
# Create home directory in /home/%u and set permissions to user / sftponly
# then do a usermod -d / user
# In Tunnelier set user home to /home

#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

#Match group sftponly
#ChrootDirectory /home/%u
#X11Forwarding no
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

but it breaks the sftp.

Comment: Can't absolutely confirm it, but a PAM module can do anything it wants, and then issue a status.  I see no reason why this wouldn't be possible.  However, it does beg a question - why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am giving people access to SFTP and a http proxy over ssh and there's a real risk they will share the login details with friends, this would cause a lot of issues so I need to make sure only one session can be active per user account at any given time.

Comment: I think the question is really better addressed as something like: 'How do I dissuade my user base from sharing passwords with their friends?'  Your solution won't stop a friend from logging on when your user isn't connected.  You might be better off sending rude emails and locking accounts of people who connect from too many different IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the number of active login sessions using utmp or utmpx, a simple loop something like this:

```
#include <utmpx.h>

int get_num_login_sessions( const char* username )
{
    int num_active_sessions = 0;
    struct utmpx* ent = NULL;
    setutxent();
    while( (ent = getutxent()) != NULL )
    {
        if( ent->ut_type == USER_PROCESS &&
            strcmp(username, ent->ut_user) == 0 )
        {
            num_active_sessions++;
        }
    }
    endutxent();
    return num_active_sessions;
}
```

See the wikipedia entry for utmp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp

If you created a pam module that did this and stacked it at the top of your auth stack you could fail if the number of active sessions was more than 0 (so long as your module was stacked as requisite or required).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "stacked it at the top of your auth stack" this is way beyond my ability so I'm going to have to find a programmer to communicate this to.  Thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: The pam configuration file consists of a "stack" of pam modules.  During authentication the pam library will go down the stack executing the instructions in each module. Depending upon: 1 - What error code the module returns 2 - What control flag it is configured with in the configuration (i.e. sufficient, required, requisite, optional) the pam library will determine whether it should continue executing modules in the stack or finish stack execution.  If you configure your module as "requisite" as the top module, you can return an authoritative failure and ensure no other module allows access

Comment: I would also suggest that you explicitly exclude the "root" user from the session number restrictions, if you do actually make this module.